# Dynamically including javascript files

Tags: assemble

I was wondering what an intuitive way is to include js files in the template. The js files are located at `src/js` and the template is at `src/template/default.hbs` and the index file at `src/index.hbs`. Is there a way that I could iterate over `src/js/**/*.js` to display them from `src/template/default.hbs`?

Comment: Are the js files for embedding in code examples? or for adding to script tags?

Comment: @jonschlinkert script tags

Comment: @PineappleUndertheSea I'm working on a plugin/helper for assemble to do something like this. I'll post with an answer and an example when it's finished.

Comment: @doowb awesome, is the wip online already? I would definitely wait for it.